# ASP.NET Core - Automatically search all controllers for a route

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

Consider the following routes:

- `/home/about` => Controller = "Home", Action = "About"
- `/home/privacy` => Controller = "Home", Action = "Privacy"
- `/account/login` => Controller = "Account", Action = "Login"
- `/account/register` => Controller = "Account", Action = "Register"
- `/user/profile` => Controller = "User", Action = "Profile"

My actions in different controllers do not overlap with each other, therefore I want these routes which are easier to read and work with:

- `/about` => Controller = "Home", Action = "About"
- `/privacy` => Controller = "Home", Action = "Privacy"
- `/login` => Controller = "Account", Action = "Login"
- `/register` => Controller = "Account", Action = "Register"
- `/profile` => Controller = "User", Action = "Profile"

And for that I have this which works:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        "main",
        "/",
        new { Controller = "Home", Action = "Index" });

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        "home",
        "/{action}/{id?}",
        new { Controller = "Home" });

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        "account",
        "/{action}/{id?}",
        new { Controller = "Account" });

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        "user",
        "/{action}/{id?}",
        new { Controller = "User" });
});
```

The problem is that for each controller I have to repeat this. Is there a way to make this automatic? Something like this:

```
// look into all controllers and find the first action that matches
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    "default",
    "/{action}/{id?}");
```

Comment: How about attributes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#combining-attribute-routes ?

Comment: Putting `[Route("/[action]")]` on each controller did work. It's not centralized but better than what I have. Thanks.

Comment: You can combine method and route on action level, e.g. `[Get("/about")]` and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with:

Instead of `UseEndpoints`, I used this:

```cs
app.MapControllers();
```

And then for each controller I used this attribute:

```cs
[Route("/[action]/{id?}")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //...
}
```

And there is just one action (for homepage) that requires its own attribute:

```cs
[Route("/")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //...
}
```